# Polymorphism With Ovals

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

### If you were given a class called BouncyFace that had the following code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class BouncyFace extends JComponent  {
        protected int xDelta = 1;
        protected int yDelta = 1;
        private Color fleshColor;
        public BouncyFace(int x, int y, int side)  {
        super();
        setBounds(x, y, side, side);
        fleshColor = new Color(214,157,106);
        setBackground(fleshColor);
        setForeground(Color.black);
    }


      public void paint(Graphics g)  {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
   }

    public void move() {
       if (getParent() != null) {
       setLocation( getX()+xDelta, getY()+yDelta );
       if ((xDelta > 0) && (getX()+getWidth() > getParent().getWidth()) ) {
           xDelta = -Math.abs(xDelta);
       } else if ((xDelta < 0) && (getX() < 0)) {
           xDelta = Math.abs(xDelta);
       }
       if ((yDelta > 0) && (getY()+getHeight() > getParent().getHeight()) ) {
           yDelta = -Math.abs(yDelta);
       } else if ((yDelta < 0) && (getY() < 0)) {
           yDelta = Math.abs(yDelta);
       }           
       repaint();
   }
```

And you were told to create a class that alters paint() so that BouncyFace draws not just an oval, but also two small ovals in it, how would you go about doing this?

Edit:

Ok, So Here is the new class I have-

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class Features extends BouncyFace
    {
      public Features(int x,int y, int side)
     {
        super(x,y,side);
        //setBounds(x,y,side,side);
    }


     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
       super.paint(g);
       //g.setColor( getBackground() );
       g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth(), getHeight());

     }
  }
```

However, I believe this overrode the old paint because it only shows me the new oval when I do this in the Driver

private Features eyes;

eyes = new Features(10,10,10);

Does this have to do with the paramters that I set? Sorry for asking so much, I am just trying to understand inheritence with polymorphism and I am completely stuck here and think its unnecessary to start a new question.

Thank you for all your insight on this problem. I have solved it and now working on another problem. Thank you stackoverflow community.

Comment: I would start by creating a new class that extends BouncyFace and then override its `paint(...)` method. Don't forget to call the super's paint method too. What happens when you try this?

Comment: I did that. However, I first of all dont know what to put into paint so that it adds onto the old paint rather than completely changing it to what is in the paint that is in the new class and not keeping the old paint. I dont know.

Comment: Ah, that is key to your problem and should be stated in the original question. The solution is to be sure to call the `super.paint(g)` method in your override. That is likely the answer to your question, and so I will post it as such.

Comment: @Cronaldo97 - Do you know what `inheritance` is? If you extend a class and overwrite its method, you still have access to the parent version of the same method by calling `super.paint(....)`.

Comment: After you call super.method() you will add whatever functionality is needed. If you need to draw two more ovals, then you would do just that.

Comment: You will have to show us `Features` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (me) I would start by creating a new class that extends BouncyFace and then override its paint(...) method. Don't forget to call the super's paint method too. What happens when you try this?
>
> (you) I did that. However, I first of all dont know what to put into paint so that it adds onto the old paint rather than completely changing it to what is in the paint that is in the new class and not keeping the old paint. I dont know.

You need to be sure to call `super.paint(g)` in your new class's `paint(Graphics g)` override. That will have it show the original oval.

Comment: OH! ok after I do super.paint(g) do I do g.drawOval(0,0,10,10)? Or will this alter the old paint considering I am trying another Oval on top of the old one

Comment: @Cronaldo97: why not try it and find out!

Comment: Edit: posted in original question

Comment: @Cronaldo97 - You are not actually *overwriting* a method in a sense that you are destroying it and creating another in its place. Nothing happens to the parent method and it's still usable with super.method() notation.  When you create your own method with the same signature in your sub-class you just letting Java know that this new class will use this new version of the method.

Comment: Then why is it only showing me the small oval and not the big oval that comes from the paint of bouncy face?

Comment: Try to draw *your* oval with a different color.

Comment: I just have another problem with creating the mouth. I created the two small ovals already but the mouth is tricky because I need to find a way to use the color in BouncyFace's paint method in the paint method of Features without altering the colors of the small ovals